# Why does function variable can have object property and number variable not?

Tags: javascript, variables

I found very mysterious thing when I am using variable.

Please see below snippet.

```js
var abc = function(){};
abc.prop = 1;

console.log(abc);
console.log(abc.prop);
```

```js
var abc = 3;
abc.prop = 1;

console.log(abc);
console.log(abc.prop);
```

#### Question1: Why does using abc.prop not outputing assertion error even if they are not object?

#### Question2: if variable's type is function, it's property can be defined and if variable's type is number, it's property cannot be defined. why does it happen?

Comment: Pretty simple...numbers don't have enumerable properties

Comment: Does functions have properties?

Comment: Yes..a function is an object.

Comment: It's a primitive value.

Comment: Then why `console.log(abc);` of first snippet showing only function, not `prop` property? How can I get function object's property?

Comment: @EgorT Because that's how `console.log()` defined.

Comment: @EgorT `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(abc)`, `Object.values(abc)`, or `Object.entries(abc)`.

Comment: Great @K._, your suggestion really make sense, please make an answer, it's really helpful understanding of function object.

Comment: Numer literals don't create objects, they're primitive `x = 1` is not the same as `x = new Number(1)`, the latter has identity while the form does not. You can't add properties to primitive values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why `console.log(abc);` of the first snippet is showing only the function body, without the `prop` property?

Because that's what `console.log()` is defined to do:
"If it's a function, just display its body."

#### How can I get `Function` object's properties?

You can use

- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(abc)` for all properties' names,
- `Object.keys(abc)` for the *enumerable* properties' names,
- `Object.values(abc)` for the *enumerable* properties' values,
- `Object.entries(abc)` for both *enumerable* properties' names and values.

like any other `Object`s.

Comment: great help understanding on funtion object

Comment: @EgorT Note that you can use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` to list properties of an object (function, ...). Try it!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, so are treated as such.  Since in your first snippet you have declared the variable abc to be of type 'function', it can have properties, just like any other js object.  In the second snippet you have declared it to be of type number, which does not allow you to declare properties.

See this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: just one question, how can I get function object's property?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to access a variable declared within the function?  Or you wish to access an attribute passed to the function?

Comment: I got answer from @K._, please see comments on question

Answer (score 1):

According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

> **Data types:**
>
> The latest ECMAScript standard defines seven data types:
>
> - Six data types that are primitives:
>
>   - Boolean
>   - Null
>   - Undefined
>   - Number
>   - String
>   - Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)
> - and Object

The primitive values do not inherit from `Object` so you can't assign properties to them.

The primitive values are copied instead of passed around using a reference to them.

You can assign properties to numbers, if the numbers are instances of `Number`:

```js
var abc = new Number(55);   // abc inherits from Object via the Number class
abc.prop = 1;               // so this is valid

console.log(abc);
console.log(abc.prop);
```

**Note:** The console log of `abc` is wrong because SO's `console.log` logs `abc` as an object where it should log it as a number. Use the browser console instead. (`abc` indeed is an object as it inherits from `Object` via the class `Number`, but it should be logged as a number since it is an instance of `Number`).

Comment: Thanks really helpful post,

Comment: oh, does number55 disappear if you define abc.prop = 1?

Comment: @EgorT It's just SO `console.log`. Try it in the browser console. Since `abc` now is an instance of `Number` and thus an instance of `Object`, SO's console get confused and log it as an object instead of a number.