# Setting a property of a primitive type appears to be a no-op. Can it be an error?

Tags: javascript

It came as a surprise to me that trying to set a property of a non-object variable seems to be allowed, and further, that it seems to be a no-op: I don't see a way to retrieve the set property.  For example (using the REPL of node.js v8.9.1):

```
> var x = 1
undefined
> typeof x
'number'
> x.foo = 'hello world'
'hello world'
> x.foo
undefined
```

Am I correct that trying to set `x.foo` is a no-op?  If so, is there a way to get the interpreter to recognize the statement `x.foo = 'hello world'` as an error - or is there an idiomatic way to prevent this kind of misuse of non-object variables?

Comment: _"If so, is there a way to get the interpreter to recognize the statement ... as an error"_ use [`'use strict'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to enable strict mode

Comment: Wait a sec. This question just been asked yesterday. Searching ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does function variable can have object property and number variable not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233550/why-does-function-variable-can-have-object-property-and-number-variable-not)

Comment: Because there is **Primitive Values** and there is **Object**. And `x instanceOf Object === false`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to make this an error. The object on which the property will be assigned is only created temporarily and then thrown away, yes, but it's not always a no-op. The object could have a setter defined (inherited):

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "foo", {
    set(val) {
        console.log("setting "+this+".foo");
    },
    configurable: true,
});
var x = 1
x.foo = 'hello world'; // setting 1.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you work with primitives as if they are objects, they will be wrapped by an object, so:

```
x.foo = "hello world"
```

is equal to:

```
new Number(x).foo = "hello world"
```

As the wrapper object is not stored anywhere, it will be garbage collected including the property youve set. So yes, setting properties of primitives is senseless.

Comment: You mean `new Number(x).foo`. Without `new`, it returns a primitive. `Number(x) === x; // true`